# how to send property as a array to backend spring boot in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following method with which I am trying to send to my backend some values as a list. the accepted json format is as follows:

```
{
value: [xyz]
}
```

But right now I am sending just the xyz part to my backend as a single value but I need to send it as the shown part.
mine looks like this: xyz according to the payload sent to the backend in network in my console.

this is my function I am using to send these to my backend:

```
 setValueForTest() {
    this.personArray = this.form.controls.selectBox.value;
    this.personArraySave = []
    this.personArray.forEach((id) => {
        this.personArraySave.push(id)
        this.api.setValueForPerson({
          body: id
        
        ).subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response)
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

the body and personArraySave is from type Person which only has id: Array as attribute

Answer (score 0):

I imagine api.setValueForPerson is a service that sends the data, if yes, maybe you can send the data something like this

```
setValueForPerson(person:Person):Observable<any>{
   return this.httpCLient.post<any>(yourURL, {value:person});
}
```

Comment: The problem is I can not change the service method I did not implement in. I just use it and the way he did it is that body expects one personmodel if I try to change it to an array I am getting the error that Person[] does not have the same properties as Person

Comment: I think the only way to do that is, changing the service as I said, or change the server acceptance code, but it seems none of the options are doable. I mean, the service is in charge to send the correct data to the back-end, there is no way you can do anything from your script, since, as you said, the service expects a Person object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who helped, the problem is fixed I just instanced an Element of the Object I am sending. Then I could work with the array element inside that model and push my values inside it.